# S3 resource not listing key for some folders

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to delete files (not folder) from multiple folders within an s3 bucket.

my code:

```
for archive in src.objects.filter(Prefix="Nightly/{folder}"):
    s3.Object(BUCKET, archive.key).delete()
```

when I do this, this deletes only files from some directory (works fine)

but for other 2 folders it deletes the folder itself.

[image]

if you see the picture, I am listing the files in each folder.
folders ***account, user, Archive*** printing an extra archieve (highlighted)
but folders ***opportunity and opphistory*** not printing key for folder. I would like to know why this key is not printing for these 2 folders, thanks.

Comment: S3 doesn't _really_ have directories. We'd have to see what `folder` is to be sure, but my guess is in some cases it doesn't have the trailing slash and in some it does.

Comment: Does it particularly matter for you if folders disappear? They aren't required for storing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no folders and files in S3. Everything is an [object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingObjects.html). So `Nightly/user/` is an object, just like `Nightly/opportunity/opportunity1.txt` is an object.

The "folders" are only [visual representation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html) made by AWS console:

> The console uses the key name prefixes (Development/, Finance/, and Private/) and delimiter ('/') to present a folder structure.

So your "folders account, user, Archive printing an extra archive (highlighted)" are just objects called `Nightly/user/`, `Nightly/account/` and `Nightly/Archive/`. Such objects are created when you click "New folder" in the AWS console (you can use also AWS SDK or CLI to create them). Your other "files" don't have such folders, because these "files" weren't created like this. Instead they where uploaded to S3 under their full name, e.g. `Nightly/opportunity/opportunity1.txt`.

Comment: @pyd No problem. Glad I could help.